# how to use count down jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, countdown

I use source in the internet. it only show right but not coundown. here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="jquery.countdown.packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#countdown').countdown({until:$.countdown.UTCDate(-8, 2011,  1 - 1, 1), format: 'DHMS', layout: 
                        '<div id="timer">' + '<hr />'+
                            '<div id="timer_days" class="timer_numbers">{dnn}</div>'+
                            '<div id="timer_hours" class="timer_numbers">{hnn}</div>'+ 
                            '<div id="timer_mins" class="timer_numbers">{mnn}</div>'+
                            '<div id="timer_seconds" class="timer_numbers">{snn}</div>'+
                            '<div id="timer_labels">'+
                                '<div id="timer_days_label" class="timer_labels">days</div>'+
                                '<div id="timer_hours_label" class="timer_labels">hours</div>'+
                                '<div id="timer_mins_label" class="timer_labels">mins</div>'+
                                '<div id="timer_seconds_label" class="timer_labels">secs</div>'+
                            '</div>'+                           
                        '</div>'                      
                    });
                });
            </script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="countdown"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is result

[image]

It only show zero value but not count down

Comment: Are you sure the jquery.countdown.packed.js is actually loaded into the page?

Comment: Because January 1st, 2011 has already passed?

Answer (score 0):

Is your until date in the past?  The documentation says the countdown will show all zeros once the until date has passed.